# How to display mysql data as table header and then all data related to that result as table data in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, pivot

I'm working on a venue programming system for festivals to update our current system of just using loads of spreadsheets. I'm trying to figure out a way to display a table that shows all subvenues related to a festival as table headings and then all timeslots related to that subvenue as table columns. I want it to look something like this at the end.

screenshot of current spreadsheet used:
[image: screenshot of current spreadsheet used.]

The idea is that you will be able to click on one of the free timeslots, and open a modal to allocate a show to that slot or display shows already attached to it. Ideally each subvenue will be drag and dropped into order but these are problems for later.

So far I'm trying to use a loop to create a table with only 1 column. have an sql query return the header and then inside that return loop have another sql query that returns all of the timeslots, then close the first loop. but this is only displaying 1 table and not looping round to return the others.

Code is

```
<?php 
  //selects subvenue  
 $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM Subvenue S
        JOIN Venue V
            ON S.venueId = V.venueId
        JOIN festvenue FV
            ON V.venueId = FV.venueId
        WHERE FV.festId = $festId;";
      
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed");

$rows = $result->num_rows;

//starts loop to display subvenues
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {

$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

$subvenueId = htmlspecialchars($row[0]);
$subvenueName = htmlspecialchars($row[2]);
    
echo <<<_END
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th id="$subvenueId">$subvenueName<th>
        </tr>
    _END;

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM TimeSlot 
 WHERE subVenId = $subvenueId 
 ORDER BY (start >= '05:00:00') desc, start;";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if (!$result) die ("Database access failed");

 $rows = $result->num_rows;
 for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j) {
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        
 $timeId = htmlspecialchars($row[0]);
 $type = htmlspecialchars($row[3]);
 $start = htmlspecialchars($row[4]);
 $end = htmlspecialchars($row[5]);
 $length = htmlspecialchars($row[8]);
        
  echo <<<_END
   <tr id="$timeId" class="timeslot-time">
      <td class="$type-$length">$start - $end</td>
   </tr>
  _END;
  }
    echo "</table>";
  }

 ?>
```

The sample data I have is below

```
Subvenue Table
+----------+---------+------------------------+
| subVenId | venueId | subVenName             |
+----------+---------+------------------------+
|        1 |       2 | Subvenue 1             |
|        2 |       2 | subvenue 2             |
+----------+---------+------------------------+

timeslot Table
+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
| timeId | festId | subVenId | type  | start    | end      | length |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
|      1 |     11 |        1 | show  | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 |     60 |
|      2 |     11 |        1 | show  | 13:30:00 | 14:30:00 |     60 |
|      3 |     11 |        1 | break | 13:00:00 | 13:30:00 |     30 |
|      4 |     11 |        1 | break | 14:30:00 | 15:00:00 |     30 |
|      5 |     11 |        1 | show  | 15:00:00 | 16:00:00 |     60 |
|      6 |     11 |        2 | show  | 16:30:00 | 17:30:00 |     60 |
|      7 |     11 |        2 | show  | 18:00:00 | 19:00:00 |     60 |
|      8 |     11 |        2 | show  | 19:30:00 | 20:30:00 |     60 |
|      9 |     11 |        1 | show  | 21:00:00 | 22:00:00 |     60 |
|     10 |     11 |        2 | show  | 22:30:00 | 23:30:00 |     60 |
+--------+--------+----------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
```

I'm not even sure a table it the best thing for this or would lists or something else be better?

At the end I want it to display

```
+-------------------+.  +-------------------+
| subvenue 1        |   | subvenue 2        |
+-------------------+.  +-------------------+
| 12:00:00-13:00:00 |   | 16:30:00-17:30:00 |
| 13:30:00-14:30:00 |   | 18:00:00-19:00:00 |
| 13:00:00-13:30:00 |   | 19:30:00-20:30:00 |
| 14:30:00-15:00:00 |   | 22:30:00-23:30:00 |
| 15:00:00-16:00:00 |.  +-------------------+
| 21:00:00-22:00:00 |
+-------------------+
etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am currently using prepared statements for all user submitted data from forms but will change this up as well to stop injection from other methods.

Comment: This is called "pivoting".  It's a notorious pain in the xxx neck in MySQL. You may want to get your php program to do this formatting.

Comment: you use same $j index in both nested loops (think those are nested because there is no formatting). and you create table inside subvenues loop so you will get separate tables for each venue. i thought you want to have a single table for the whole fest?

Comment: I'm not too worried about if each subvenue is in it's own table or in one table. whatever will work best.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out. I decided to output a series of lists instead of using a table.

Apart from that my main fix was instead of using the same $sql and $stmt variables in the mySQL query I used $subSql and $subStmt for the second query.

```
require_once "header.php";

$festId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["festival_Id"]);

?>

    <div id="programming" class="tabcontent">
    <h2 >Programming</h2><br>  
    
<?php  

     //gets the subvenue and starts first loop

$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM Subvenue S
    JOIN Venue V
        ON S.venueId = V.venueId
    JOIN festvenue FV
        ON V.venueId = FV.venueId
    WHERE FV.festId = ?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  header("location: ../festival.php?error=sqlerror&festival_Id".$festId);
  exit();
}

else {
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $festId);
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   $rows = $result->num_rows;

   for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
   {
       $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
       $subVenueId = htmlspecialchars($row[0]);
       $subVenueName = htmlspecialchars($row[2]);
    
   echo <<<_END
       <div id="$subVenueId" class="programme">
         <ul>
            <li class="programme-heading">$subVenueName</li>
              <ul>
    _END;

        //select all timeslots with that subvenue   
        $subSql = "SELECT * FROM TimeSlot 
                WHERE subVenId = ?
                ORDER BY (start >= '05:00:00') desc, start;";
        $subStmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($subStmt, $subSql)) {
            header("location: ../festival.php? 
            error=sqlerror&festival_Id".$festId);
            exit();
        }
        else {
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($subStmt, "s", $subVenueId);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($subStmt);
           $subResult = $subStmt->get_result();
                
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subResult)) {
              $timeId = htmlspecialchars($row['timeId']);
              $type = htmlspecialchars($row['type']);
              $start = htmlspecialchars($row['start']);
              $end = htmlspecialchars($row['end']);
              $length = htmlspecialchars($row['length']);
                    
        echo <<<_END
              <li id="[$timeId" class="$type-$length">$start - $end</li>
        _END;][1]
                }
            }
            echo "</ul></ul></div>";
        }
}
```

That looks exactly how I wanted it. in the initial question